# Looking for a paper: AI in human host

Tags: reference-request, language, artificial-intelligence

I am searching for a paper where participants were confronted with a (female) person, who gave answers according to a computer algorithm. She had an earpiece that gave her the answers and was trained to simultaneously listen and speak.

Some participants thought that she was acting a bit off, but none recognized that they are talking to a computer. I think the aim of the study was some sort of turing test.

Hope anyone can help me find it. I don't know how to look for it anymore...

Comment: Welcome. Can you indicate if it's a new paper (say >2010), mediocre (2000<2010<) or 'old' (<2000)? And are you sure it's a scientific paper, or may it be an unpublished report from one of your professors (or the likes)? Lastly, but certainly not least, the aim of the study is really important, as searching specific papers based on keywords in the methods is notoriously hard. *Some sort of Turing test* is not enough.

Comment: Thank you so much for looking into it!  
I only read the news article _about_ the study last year, so I assume it came out in the past 2 years. 
I did not look into the actual paper at the time as it did not spark initial interest. So I can not tell you where and if it was published.
As the article put it, one of the goals was to find out if participants can recognize that they are talking to a computer program if the interface a human person. 
I'm sorry that I can not give you more info. As I said I wasn't paying too much attention to it back then...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally!

I found a news article explaining the **[Echoborg](https://arstechnica.com/science/2015/05/human-ai-echoborgs-make-chatbots-more-real-but-still-fail-turing-test/)**.
The research was done in 2015 by Kevin Corti and Alex Gillespi at the London School of Economics and Political Science. Published at Frontiers of Psychology: https://doi.org/10.3389/fpsyg.2015.00634

Comment: Don't hesitate accepting your own answer!

Comment: I have to wait 17 hours before i can :)